# External Hard Drive opens with Puddletag and not Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I am using gnome-shell 3.4
My external hard drive prompts to open with Puddletag and when I clock on my removeable devices, they open with puddletag. WHY is this?

Comment: Nautilus shortcuts in the gnome-shell menubar open up with Puddletag.

Comment: I use all-in-one-places the links open using Puddletag.

Comment: same problem here.  I am using Linux Mint with nemo as the filemanager (Nautilus 3.4 fork).  Also, gnome keyboard shortcut to open "home" is set to "ctrl + alt + e" for me.  This sequence also opens puddletag!  Very strange indeed.  Will need to uninstall puddletag for now.

Answer (score 2):

When you plug-in your HD and when it prompts to choose an application: Choose "**Nautilus** "

or

Right click on folder -> Properties -> Open with -> choose "**Nautilus**"

or

Right click on folder -> **Open with** directly -> Other application -> Choose "**Files/Nautilus**" -> Remember this application

Comment: There is no option to open the hard drive with anything.
Also, there is no option to choose open with Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the system-wide default.list files that control default applications to confirm they have this line:

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

Instead of "something else" to handle opening directories.  From what I can tell (I am on Linux Mint 13) the files that you may need to check are:

```
/etc/gnome/defaults.list

/etc/gnome/defaults.list.dpkg-old

/usr/share/applications/defaults.list

/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list

/usr/share/linuxmint/common/artwork/mime/defaults.list
```

I have noticed if I only change /etc/gnome/defaults.list or /usr/share/applications/defaults.list that the change is *not permanent* and will be reset after reboot.

I needed to modify these to use nemo.desktop instead of nautilus.desktop (in Mint I have purged nautilus as I use nemo as the file manager).  When these files referenced nautilus.desktop (although nautilus was removed), I also had puddletag being called to open a folder!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when plugging in an external drive, Thunar was getting opened but I wanted Nautilus. I went to Thunar's preferences and disabled "volume management", not totally a solution but close to, at least Thunar doesn't automatically open now

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had this problem in the past and it’s just resurfaced on moving distro. I’m not sure what causes it, but the fact it’s happened more than once with Puddletag might suggest something’s wrong there.

My solution comes from instructions about how to change from Nautilus to Nemo, since that involves changing the program that handles certain MIME types.

Use this command in a terminal.

**Nautilus**

`xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

**Nemo**

`xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`